# What is needTime on MongoDB cursor.explain("executionStats")?

Tags: mongodb

I was checking that my query is optimum or not. For that I used Cursor.explain("executionStats"). At there few keys present which I am curious to know about.

So I found needTime. I researched on MongoDB Official Documentation but unfortunately, I was not able to understand. Is there anyone who help me out regarding this.

This is my result:

```
"winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "transformBy" : {

                                "views" : 0,

                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "createdate" : -1
                                },
                                "limitAmount" : 20,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "filter" : {
                                                        "post_status" : {
                                                                "$eq" : 1
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "keyPattern" : {

                                                                "user_id" : 1,
                                                                "lastmodified" : -1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "user_id_1_lastmodified_-1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {

                                                                "user_id" : [ ],
                                                                "lastmodified" : [ ]
                                                        },
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {

                                                                "user_id" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "lastmodified" : [
                                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 20,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 1,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 386,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 375,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "nReturned" : 20,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 409,
                        "advanced" : 20,
                        "needTime" : 388,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 3,
                        "restoreState" : 3,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "transformBy" : {

                                "views" : 0,

                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT",
                                "nReturned" : 20,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 409,
                                "advanced" : 20,
                                "needTime" : 388,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 3,
                                "restoreState" : 3,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "sortPattern" : {
                                        "createdate" : -1
                                },
                                "memUsage" : 19348,
                                "memLimit" : 33554432,
                                "limitAmount" : 20,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                        "nReturned" : 225,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                        "works" : 388,
                                        "advanced" : 225,
                                        "needTime" : 162,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 3,
                                        "restoreState" : 3,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                                "filter" : {
                                                        "post_status" : {
                                                                "$eq" : 1
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                "nReturned" : 225,
                                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                                "works" : 387,
                                                "advanced" : 225,
                                                "needTime" : 161,
                                                "needYield" : 0,
                                                "saveState" : 3,
                                                "restoreState" : 3,
                                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                                "docsExamined" : 375,
                                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                                "inputStage" : {
                                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                        "nReturned" : 375,
                                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                                        "works" : 387,
                                                        "advanced" : 375,
                                                        "needTime" : 11,
                                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                                        "saveState" : 3,
                                                        "restoreState" : 3,
                                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                                        "keyPattern" : {

                                                                "user_id" : 1,
                                                                "lastmodified" : -1
                                                        },
                                                        "indexName" : "user_id_1_lastmodified_-1",
                                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {

                                                                "user_id" : [ ],
                                                                "lastmodified" : [ ]
                                                        },
                                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                                        "indexBounds" : {

                                                                "user_id" : [
                                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                                ],
                                                                "lastmodified" : [
                                                                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                                                ]
                                                        },
                                                        "keysExamined" : 386,
                                                        "seeks" : 1,
                                                        "dupsTested" : 386,
                                                        "dupsDropped" : 11,
                                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
```

Comment: I don't know what needTime is, but a lot of those counters are basically different ways of expressing that mongo was waiting a while for some resource and are generally higher when you have a slower queries. For a query like this, one of the first things to check is whether `nReturned` is the same number as `totalKeysExamined` and `totalDocsExamined`. If they're not, you should look into the different stages -and see what's going wrong (your index isn't able to fully satisfy the query, especially the sort part)